# Embedding a navigation controller in a container

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uicontainerview

I have a ViewController that is the storyboard entry point, in this viewcontroller I have a view at the bottom with a fix height and position, above it I have a container view which embeds a navigation controller which has another viewcontroller as its root view.

When I run my app the root view of the navigation controllers is the only thing I see. It seems that the navigationcontroller overlaps my bottom fix view of my parent view controller.

How can I make my fix view appear? Why does it happen so?

Please help.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not to add the fixed view in bottom inside the view controller who has the navigationController as parent

Comment: because that view controller will be changed with other view controllers many times over, and i wish to keep that fixed view across these switches

Answer (score -3):

Finally figured out what the problem was.
I forgot that i am using the MMDrawerController and because of it, no matter what i was doing in the storyboard it would reflect in the simulator since my implementation of the drawer was replacing from the launch the rootviewcontroller from appdelegate

Comment: This answer makes absolutely zero sense to anyone except you. You should edit the question to add more context to it so it can help others out.